# How to add Token into HTTP Post method in c#?

Tags: c#, http-post, token

hello guys this is my task method, it is http post method, now I want to add it Token like

`httpWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Some_Token";`

so, I am newbie and don't know how to do that, can someone help me?

```
            Task t = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                string GetReferralsByPersonalIdNumberURL = "http://somehost/api/Referral/GetExistingClaimsByReferralNumber";
                GetExistingClaimsByReferralNumberClass cust = new GetExistingClaimsByReferralNumberClass() { referralNumber = ReferalNumFromMedicine, pharmacyID = PharmacyIDFromMedicine, };
                var json = _Serializer.Serialize(cust);
                var response = await Request(HttpMethod.Post, GetReferralsByPersonalIdNumberURL, json, new Dictionary<string, string>());

               //  Request.Headers["Authorization"] = "SomeToken"; 
                string responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                da = convertJsonStringToDataset(responseText);
                // List<YourCustomClassModel> serializedResult = _Serializer.Deserialize<List<YourCustomClassModel>>(responseText);

                //  Console.WriteLine(da.GetXml());
                // Console.ReadLine();

            });
            t.Wait();
```

And this is `request` method used in [webmethod]

```
static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Request(HttpMethod pMethod, string pUrl, string pJsonContent, Dictionary<string, string> pHeaders)
        {
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
            httpRequestMessage.Method = pMethod;
            httpRequestMessage.RequestUri = new Uri(pUrl);
            foreach (var head in pHeaders)
            {
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(head.Key, head.Value);
            }
            switch (pMethod.Method)
            {
                case "POST":
                    HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(pJsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    httpRequestMessage.Content = httpContent;
                    break;

            }

            return await _Client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
        }
```

I think i have to change inside request method, and also i think i did it in another way, hope you guys will understand what i am to trying

Comment: Please add `Request` method code

Comment: where is this `Request` class being imported from?

Comment: I edited, this is my whole method, is that you need?

Comment: You have this line `await Request(HttpMethod.Post, GetReferralsByPersonalIdNumberURL, json, new Dictionary<string, string>());
`. Please provide the code inside this `Request` method

Comment: I edited it can you look?

Comment: do something like this `httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `Request` like this

```
var headers = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "Authorization", "SomeToken" }
};

var response = await Request(HttpMethod.Post, GetReferralsByPersonalIdNumberURL, json, headers);
```

Comment: tank you, it debugs successfully

Answer (score 1):

add a new Authorization header like this, as you're doing in the loop

```
 httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
```